# ul grid without specific borders

Tags: css

I want to remove the border of the corners same as shown in following attached image without using the specific classes as this grid is generating number of columns on run time as per data. Please guide me how can I achieve this?

[image]

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/DWPNH/)

```
HTML:
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul{list-style:none; width:260px;}
ul li{
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
    margin-left:-1px;
    margin-top:-1px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can drop `border-bottom` and `border-right`. reset `padding` on ul and set `overflow` to `hidden`:  **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DWPNH/4/)**

You can tune box model too if you wish to, but unnecessary to see it **[working](http://jsfiddle.net/DWPNH/3/)**

---

[and if i remove an li ?](http://jsfiddle.net/DWPNH/5/)

---

[does ul width matters ?](http://jsfiddle.net/DWPNH/7/)

Answer (score 1):

using following CSS (for this particular context)

```
     ul{ list-style: none; width: 260px; }
     ul li{
        display: block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        float: left;
     }

     ul li:nth-child(5n){
        border-right: none;;
     }

     ul li:nth-child(n + 21){ border-bottom: none; }
```

you'll not need the negative margin hack to hide overlapping borders

Comment: Using specific numbers won't work here - "This grid is generating number of columns on run time as per data"

Comment: I agree with Dipaks. We cannot use specific numbers in css as we don't know exactly the number of columns or row in the grid. These numbers can be change on every load.

Comment: you're right and that's why I put _for this particular context_ in the answer. This might not fully answer your question but it puts you on the right track. The way I would tackle the dynamic column thing is to put a `col4` or `colX` class on `<ul>`, and write CSS for possible `colX`.

Comment: I know that now there could be a counter argument of "How many colX classes can be defined in CSS", which you'll have to assess knowing your code. I hope it helps :)